# How can I scrape all the documents on a webpage using wget

Tags: wget

so this is something that I'm doing for research purposes.

I'm trying to scrape all the files from this link

https://services.crtc.gc.ca/pub/ListeInterventionList/Default-Defaut.aspx?en=2015-134&dt=i&lang=e&S=C&PA=t&PT=nc&PST=a

wget recognizes the characters in this URL as external commands like dt=. All the files are hiding behind links. What command can I use with wget in order to scrape all the files into a folder?

Answer (score 1):

To get wget to download recursively there is a `-r` option. This can grab quite a lot and take time, so if you know that the links you care about are only one level down, you can use `-l 1` or another integer if you want to go down to a specific depth.

Not related to wget per-se, but I suspect you are not escaping the characters of the URL either and your shell is interpreting them. You must preceed any special characters with `\` (back-slash). So if your URL is:

```
http://www.somewhere.com/file.php?p1=v1&p2=v2
```

On most shells you would have to enter the command as follows:

```
wget -r -l 1 http://www.somewhere.com/file.php\?p1=v1\&p2=v2
```

The exact characters that need escaping depends on the shell but this is what I would use with tcsh.